# How to replace a string of text with input from another file

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed, cat

I am working on a script to configure a server. Basically the script installs several services and copies configuration files in to place.

I would like to replace the username in one of the configuration files with the content of another file.
The input file is one line of text which contains the username.
The config file has multiple lines of text but only one line refers to the username.

How do I replace the username of the config file with the username stored in the input file?

Comment: How could you identify the line containing the user name in both files?

Comment: Hello Jacob, 
In the input file there is just one word which is the username.
In the config file the place where I have to enter the user name is in the line USER:'username'

Comment: Ah, I see, will edit the answer.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now the script assumes the source file only contains the username, in the targeted config file everything after `USER:` is replaced by the username in the sourcefile.

Comment: I tested the script and it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: perfect! glad it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the actual username in the targeted file is preceded by `USER:` (if not, change it in the head section of the script), here is a python solution to do the job.

Simply copy the script into an empty file, save it as `replace_username.py` and run it with the source file (with the correct user name) and the destination file as arguments:

```
python3 /path/to/replace_username.py <sourcefile> <destination_file>
```

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

source = sys.argv[1]       # the file with the password you want to insert
destination = sys.argv[2]  # the targeted configuration file
prefix="USER:"             # prefix, check if it is exactly as in your files

with open(source) as src:
    name = src.read().strip()

with open(destination) as edit:
    lines = edit.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if lines[i].startswith(prefix):
        lines[i] = prefix+name+"\n"

with open(destination, "wt") as edit:
    for line in lines:
        edit.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the username in a variable and use `sed` to change the configfile:

```
#! /bin/bash
username=$(< /path/to/username)
sed -i~ -e "s/username=XXX/username=$username/"
```

The config file in this example should contain the line `username=XXX`. The username shouldn't contain `/` (some other non-alphanumeric characters might be problematic, too).

(Untested.)